# tornado-maven-osgi-project template for IntelliJ does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, osgi, apache-felix, tornadofx

I successfully installed and ran TornadoFX 1.7.14 and all its required bundles on Apache Felix 5.6.10 OSGi. Then created a project using `tornado-maven-osgi-project` template in IntelliJ 2017.3 community edition, then using `mvn package` created a bundle out of it. I have not changed anything in the generated classes. Just updated Kotlin from 1.2.21 to 1.2.31. I then installed the bundle on Felix without any problem. However, when I start the bundle it throws the following exception(s): This happens also with Kotlin 1.2.21. The maven dependency for TornadoFX and the installed TornadoFX are both 1.7.14.

```
Waiting for JavaFX Runtime Startup.[Done]
ERROR: Bundle no.tornado.tornadofx [25] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 77
Exception Details:
  Location:
    tornadofx/CSSKt.toSelector(Ljava/lang/String;)Ltornadofx/CssSelector; @123: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a12 1ab8 000f bb01 e959 2ac0 00a1 4cb2
    0000010: 01c8 b601 ec4d 3a0b 3a0a 033e 2c2b 1db6
    0000020: 01f0 3a0c 190a 190b 190c c000 1c4c 3a0b
    0000030: 3a0a 2b4d bb01 f259 2b10 0ab8 01f8 b701
    0000040: fbc0 01fd 4e2c b900 2001 003a 0419 04b9
    0000050: 0026 0100 9900 2a19 04b9 002a 0100 3a05
    0000060: 2d19 05c0 007b 3a06 3a0c 1906 b802 013a
    0000070: 0d19 0c19 0db9 0205 0200 57a7 ffd2 2dc0
    0000080: 0207 3a0c 190a 190b 190c c001 fd4c 3a0b
    0000090: 3a0a 2b4d 2c2c b902 0a01 00bd 020c b902
    00000a0: 1002 0059 c700 0ebb 00ac 5913 0212 b700
    00000b0: afbf 3a0c 190a 190b 190c c002 1459 beb8
    00000c0: 021a c002 14b7 021d b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@77,{Object[#123],Object[#28],Object[#28],Object[#509],Object[#34],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Uninitialized[#6],Uninitialized[#6],Object[#4]},{})
    same_frame(@126)
    full_frame(@178,{Object[#123],Object[#509],Object[#509],Object[#509],Object[#34],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Uninitialized[#6],Uninitialized[#6],Object[#519]},{Object[#83]})
)
java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 77
Exception Details:
  Location:
    tornadofx/CSSKt.toSelector(Ljava/lang/String;)Ltornadofx/CssSelector; @123: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a12 1ab8 000f bb01 e959 2ac0 00a1 4cb2
    0000010: 01c8 b601 ec4d 3a0b 3a0a 033e 2c2b 1db6
    0000020: 01f0 3a0c 190a 190b 190c c000 1c4c 3a0b
    0000030: 3a0a 2b4d bb01 f259 2b10 0ab8 01f8 b701
    0000040: fbc0 01fd 4e2c b900 2001 003a 0419 04b9
    0000050: 0026 0100 9900 2a19 04b9 002a 0100 3a05
    0000060: 2d19 05c0 007b 3a06 3a0c 1906 b802 013a
    0000070: 0d19 0c19 0db9 0205 0200 57a7 ffd2 2dc0
    0000080: 0207 3a0c 190a 190b 190c c001 fd4c 3a0b
    0000090: 3a0a 2b4d 2c2c b902 0a01 00bd 020c b902
    00000a0: 1002 0059 c700 0ebb 00ac 5913 0212 b700
    00000b0: afbf 3a0c 190a 190b 190c c002 1459 beb8
    00000c0: 021a c002 14b7 021d b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@77,{Object[#123],Object[#28],Object[#28],Object[#509],Object[#34],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Uninitialized[#6],Uninitialized[#6],Object[#4]},{})
    same_frame(@126)
    full_frame(@178,{Object[#123],Object[#509],Object[#509],Object[#509],Object[#34],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Uninitialized[#6],Uninitialized[#6],Object[#519]},{Object[#83]})

        at tornadofx.Stylesheet.<clinit>(CSS.kt:99)
        at tornadofx.App.<init>(App.kt:70)
        at tornadofx.App.<init>(App.kt:55)
        at tornadofx.App.<init>(App.kt:55)
        at services.nano.wb.app.DashboardApp.<init>(DashboardApp.kt:6)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
        at tornadofx.osgi.impl.ApplicationListener.startDelegate(ApplicationListener.kt:105)
        at tornadofx.osgi.impl.ApplicationListener.startDelegateIfPossible(ApplicationListener.kt:87)
        at tornadofx.osgi.impl.ApplicationListener.serviceChanged(ApplicationListener.kt:79)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:990)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:838)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:545)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4595)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3587)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:348)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:355)
        at tornadofx.osgi.ApplicationProviderKt.registerApplication(ApplicationProvider.kt:17)
        at services.nano.wb.app.Activator.start(Activator.kt:12)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2240)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2146)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1373)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

These are the installed bundles:

```
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.6.10)|5.6.10
    1|Active     |    1|jansi (1.16.0)|1.16.0
    2|Active     |    1|JLine Bundle (3.5.1)|3.5.1
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.10)|2.0.10
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (1.0.2)|1.0.2
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo JLine Shell (1.0.10)|1.0.10
    6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (1.0.10)|1.0.10
    8|Active     |    1|Apache Apache HttpCore OSGi bundle (4.4.9)|4.4.9
    9|Active     |    1|Apache Apache HttpClient OSGi bundle (4.5.5)|4.5.5
   10|Active     |    1|org.osgi:org.osgi.service.cm (1.5.0.201505202024)|1.5.0.201505202024
   11|Active     |    1|Apache Commons Logging (1.2.0)|1.2.0
   12|Resolved   |    1|JavaFX 8 OSGi extension bundle (8.0.1)|8.0.1
   13|Active     |    1|kotlin-osgi-bundle (1.2.31)|1.2.31
   23|Active     |    1|JSR 353 (JSON Processing) Default Provider (1.0.4)|1.0.4
   25|Active     |    1|TornadoFX (1.7.14)|1.7.14
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837176/kotlin-verifyerror-uninitialized-object-exists-on-backward-branch-90

Comment: I updated IntelliJ to 2018.1, Java to JDK 1.9.0.162, with Kotlin 1.2.30. Creating and running Koltin projects has no problem. Only when I create a TornadoFX OSGi project using the provided `tornado-maven-osgi-project`.

Comment: Interesting. The error message includes the following message: "Error exists in the bytecode". This suggests to me a bug in the Kotlin compiler.